# Low search returning results from other channels when no options are selected

Tags: low-search

I have a (low) search form set up like so (stripped out example) to search a collection Ive set up called 'walks'. This collection is for the 'walks' channel.

```
{exp:low_search:form collection="walks" query="{segment_3}" result_page="walks/results"}

  <input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywords"/>

  and then a category dropdown and two sets of checkbox fields to 
  search within checkbox fields in the entries.

{/exp:low_search:form}
```

It all works perfectly, apart from whenever I perform a search without entering a keyword, selecting a category from the dropdown, or checking any checkboxes. When doing this it returns entries from other channels.

Any idea why it would do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per version 3.0, Low Search [doesn't accept filter-parameters in the Form tag](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs#to-3.0). Instead, you should move these parameters to the Results tag or add them as (hidden) input fields inside the Form tag.

So, try removing the collection="" parameter (which is part of the [Keywords filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#keywords)) from the Form tag, and add it to the Results tag instead.

Comment: Thanks Low, must have missed that change. Moving the param to the results tag works fine. Thanks again!